# There is Alice and there is Bob. But what is the name of the malicious user?

Tags: terminology

I know it is a kinda funny and maybe even naive question but its still security related, so I decided to ask.

Bob and Alice are widely used names indicating the two end-users/parties for web protocols. But in security there is also a third entity, the malicious user. I read a blog post naming that entity "Maria". I giggled and wondered:

Is "Maria" actually a well-established name for the malicious user, in the security industry?

Comment: [Wikipedia: Alice and Bob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob) lists all commonly used characters. And it was actually the first hit I got when [searching for "alice bob"](https://www.google.com/search?q=alice+bob). Hint: it is usually Mallory.

Comment: That's actually cool, thanks

Comment: It was  Eve, however, some people don't like it since Adam/Eve and Oscar is preferred. There is no standard.

Comment: @kelalaka I always assumed "eve" was chosen because it relates to "evil"

Comment: @MechMK1 yes, however, what you see is not the same as what others see.

Comment: @kelalaka Sure, it's opinion-based. The explanation that Eve is "eavesdropping" and Mallory is "Malicious" makes sense though.

Comment: @MechMK1 keep in mind that eavesdropping doesn't cover all attack methods. It is a passive attack. I hope calling Oscar doesn't create a Karen type in the community. Also the [Mallory](https://www.babynames.com/name/mallory#:~:text=The%20name%20Mallory%20means%20Ill,TV%20show%20%22Family%20Ties.%22) is in French

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a funny question, I think it depends on the kind of attack you're performing.

For example, when you're trying to eavesdrop a communication, it's usually "Eve" who's doing it.
For more generic attacks, "Mallory" (Coming from "malice") is the most common choice.

As Stephen Ullrich pointed out in his comment, here's a list of all the commonly used characters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob

Comment: In ***some*** texts, Eve is explicitly restricted to be a passive eavesdropper (e.g. listening only to a radio broadcast), while Mallory can perform Man-in-the-Middle attacks and more generally is an active adversary.

Answer (score 5):

Eve is an eavesdropper. Mallory is an active attacker. Carol and Dan and Erin are third and fourth and fifth participants respectively. Trudy is an intruder and Craig is a password cracker. Michael or Mike may be an alternative to Eve but Maria is an innocent.